# Programmatically create invoice a single item of an order

Tags: magento-1.7, invoice, custom

I would like to create an invoice for a particular item only. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I've asked this question a while back, be sure to search the website before posting new questions.

[Programmatically invoice a single product off of an order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11045/programmatically-invoice-a-single-product-off-of-an-order)

Let me know if you run into any hassles.

**Edit:** as per comment:

```
foreach($items as $item){
    $qty_to_invoice = x; //where x is the amount you wish to invoice
    <!-- please note that if you don't want to invoice this product, set this value to 0 -->
    $qtys[$item->getId()] = $qty_to_invoice;
    <!-- Note that the ->getId() method gets the item_id on the order, not the product_id -->
}
```

You're going to need to edit this code for your specific case, otherwise it will, as you mentioned, invoice all the products on order.

Comment: I try this code but its create all item invoice.

Comment: I've edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Not solved its create all order item invoice

Comment: I have tested this code and it works correctly for me, you may want to revisit the section where you are indicating which products you want on the invoice.