# How to auto invoice a single item of an order?

Tags: orders, adminhtml, invoice, sales

I am trying to invoice a single product of an order. I have found exactly the same question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11045/programmatically-invoice-a-single-product-off-of-an-order). So i have written a observer of **sales_order_save_commit_after** event and then integrate that code into my observer. But it seems like it is not working for me. Because When i place an order, it stucks in a loop. Am i making a mistake?

```
class Emmagento_Autoinvoice_Model_Observer {

public $order;
public $incrementid;

function afterSalesOrderSaveCommitAfter(&$event) {

    return $this->__process($event);
}

protected function __process($event) {

    $this->order = $event->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->order->getId());
    $this->incrementid = $order->getIncrementId();
    if (!$this->order->getId()) {
        return $this;
    }
    else {

        $this->createInvoice();
    }
}

protected function createInvoice() {
 $orderState = $this->order->getState();
 $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->incrementid);
 $items = $order->getAllItems();
 $qtys = array();
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    $_sku = $item->getSku();
                    $_catalog = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                    $_productId = $_catalog->getIdBySku($_sku);
                    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productId);
                    if ($_product->getAutoinvoice() == "1") {
                        $qty_to_invoice = $item->getQtyOrdered(); 
                    } else {
                        $qty_to_invoice = 0;
                    }
                    $qtys[$item->getId()] = $qty_to_invoice;
                }
 $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice($qtys);
 $amount = $invoice->getGrandTotal();
                    $invoice->register()->pay();
                    $invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

                    $history = $invoice->getOrder()->addStatusHistoryComment(
                        'Partial amount of $' . $amount . ' captured automatically.', false
                    );

                    $history->setIsCustomerNotified(true);

                    $order->save();

                    Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                        ->addObject($invoice)
                        ->addObject($invoice->getOrder())
                        ->save();
                    $invoice->save();
                    $invoice->sendEmail(true, ''); //set this to false to not send the invoice via email
}
```

Comment: Check your **increment id **, where is this t coming from?

Comment: Adarsh you may check now. i have written complete code now

Answer (score 1):

In observer you can get order by calling `$observer->getEvent()->getOrder();`, why not use this method.

Try this code:

```
<?php
class Emmagento_Autoinvoice_Model_Observer {

public function afterSalesOrderSaveCommitAfter($observer) {
 $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
 $orderState = $order->getState();
 $items = $order->getAllItems();
 $qtys = array();
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    $_sku = $item->getSku();
                    $_catalog = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                    $_productId = $_catalog->getIdBySku($_sku);
                    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productId);
                    if ($_product->getAutoinvoice() == "1") {
                        $qty_to_invoice = $item->getQtyOrdered(); 
                    } else {
                        $qty_to_invoice = 0;
                    }
                    $qtys[$item->getId()] = $qty_to_invoice;
                }
 $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice($qtys);
 $amount = $invoice->getGrandTotal();
                    $invoice->register()->pay();
                    $invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

                    $history = $invoice->getOrder()->addStatusHistoryComment(
                        'Partial amount of $' . $amount . ' captured automatically.', false
                    );

                    $history->setIsCustomerNotified(true);

                    $order->save();

                    Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                        ->addObject($invoice)
                        ->addObject($invoice->getOrder())
                        ->save();
                    $invoice->save();
                    $invoice->sendEmail(true, ''); //set this to false to not send the invoice via email
}
```

I haven't tested it, however have referenced bottom part (codes after getting `$order`) to your provided link, and this should work.

Comment: i tried this code. The output is same. I figured it out that it stucks in a loop. May be in this code, i am calling the same event each time.

Comment: Looking to your code, I don't see any `if` statement to tell magento to do, aren't you trying to invoice only one item?

Comment: You can find if ($_product->getAutoinvoice() == "1") inside createInvoice function.

Comment: Where this `getAutoinvoice()` data coming from? is it custom column?

Comment: It is product attribute.