# Automatically partially invoice when shipped

Tags: create-invoice

I need to invoice my order automatically whenever shipment is done, but if say I ship only one item of multiple items order then invoice should also be created for only that item not for all.
I am using following code after setting a observer whenever shipped but it is invoicing all items even if I ship just one:

```
public function invoicedStatusChange($observer)
    {
       $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
       $order = $shipment->getOrder();
       if($order->canInvoice())
       {
           $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();
           $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
           $invoice->register();
           $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
           ->addObject($invoice)
           ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
           $transactionSave->save();
       }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/11075/519

You need to include the qty of each item shipped

```
if($order->canInvoice()){
  foreach(get item collection just ship){
    $qtys[$item->getId()] = $item->getQtyShipped();
  }

  Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice($qtys);

}
```

Take a look at database table `sales_flat_order_item`

```
qty_canceled
qty_invoiced
qty_ordered
qty_refunded
qty_shipped
```

Note: you may need to get the qty from the $shipment, since the above fields store the total

Comment: I am new to magento, so can you please elaborate, as now how can i fetch this value for $qty_to_invoice

Comment: Need to generate the invoice automatically once the shipment is created. [Magento 2.3.3 EE]